# Stopping A Google Compute Resource with Ansible

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

It is great that you can create a new GCP instance with Ansible but how do you terminate the instance?

I don't see a command to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so it appears that all you have to do is set the state of the resource to "absent"

So it would look something like:

```
- name: detroy instance
  gcp_compute_instance:
     state: absent
     name: "{{servername}}"
     zone: "{{ zone }}"
     project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
     auth_kind: "{{ gcp_cred_kind }}"
     service_account_file: "{{ gcp_cred_file }}"
```

Comment: Are you sure? According to documentation, "state: absent" removes the resource. "status: TERMINATED" would stop the compute instance.